# How to determine text's language using Android Mobile Vision Api

Tags: android, mobile, ocr, android-vision, vision-api

I am using mobile vision API and successfully able to detect text in all supported languages.

Now I want to determine the langue of detected text i.e if its English, French etc. I have explored the API documentation but I am not able to find any method to get that.
I am following [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision) and I have gone through the API [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/package-summary)

Is there a workaround to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. I found this method in documentation:

```
line.getLanguage();
```

but this method is returning empty string.
Maybe you will have more lack. Link to docs:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/Line.html#getLanguage()

#### Update 02.11.2018

I spoke with some firebasers at Firebase Summit and i got info that language feature now works for cloud text recognition, but it is unavailable for Mobile Vision :(

Comment: I have tried using this method and I am getting "und" instead of empty string. Not so lucky though. anyway, thanks for coming up with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getLanguage method on the entire returned TextBlock](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextBlock.html#getLanguage()), this should work.